# Can I set parameter using NavigationContext.QueryString? (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

Can I pass value to Navigation Context like this:

```
NavigationContext.QueryString["param1"] = "PARAM1";
```

Is it a good way to set parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, why you need to store some parameters in `NavigationContext.QueryString`? There are exists another good places for this.

If you want to pass parameters to another page, use this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SomePage.xaml?param1=PARAM1"))
```

if you need to save some values to the state dictionary, you can use [`PhoneApplicationService.Current.State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.state%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) (global) or [`PhoneApplicationPage.State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.state%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) (page specific)

Comment: The State dictionaries are persisted upon tombstoning. It might not be a desired behavior.